# Does the vhost-user driver ensures the distribution of traffic between multiple RX queues?

Tags: rss, dpdk, multiqueue

I have a question for you. I know that vhost-user NICs can be configured with many  RX/TX queues, but does the vhost-user driver ensures the distribution of traffic between RX queues?

I used the sample application l3fdw to switch traffic between two vhost-user NICs, each with 4 queues. The traffic was generated using TREX (and testpmd also), running inside a VM. When I traced my experiment, I noticed that the traffic was only received in queue "0", while the other RX queues were empty.

The l3fdw app tells me that "Port 0 modified RSS hash function based on hardware support,requested:0xa38c configured:0". For offloading capabilities, testpmd indicates that the vhost-user nic NIC has only support for VLAN STRIP (and not for RSS)!

I appreciate any clarification on this matter.

Thank you,

PS:

- DPDK version: 19.08
- Qemu version: 4.2.1

Adele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for the original question `does the vhost-user driver ensures the distribution of traffic between RX queues?` is

> There is no mechanism like RSS or RTE_FLOW from DPDK Libraries which will ensure software packet distribution on the RX queues of VHOST NIC.

@AdelBelkhiri there are multiple aspects to be clarified to understand this better.

1. Features supported by [VHOST PMD](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/vhost.html) do not advertise either RTE_FLOW or RSS.
2. Driver code for [vhost pmd](http://git.dpdk.org/dpdk/tree/drivers/net/vhost) in file `rte_eth_vhost.c` does not advertise RSS or RTE_FLOW capability

there is an [article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/configure-vhost-user-multiqueue-for-ovs-with-dpdk.html) which describes the use of OVS and Multiple queues. The RSS is configured on the Physical NIC with 2 RX queues. The RSS is done on the Physical NIC, 2 separate threads picks the packets from the Physical RX queue and puts the same in VHOST queues. Thus achieving `pass-through` RSS.

hence in your case where you have 2 VM with 2 NIC ports each having 4 queues, please try 8 PMD threads on OVS to concurrently fwd packets between queues. Where the TREX (TX) VM will ensure to put appropriate packets into each queue seperately.

But the simple answer is **there is no RSS or RTE_FLOW logic to distribute traffic**